# capturing the clicked option in bootstrap selectpicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap selectpicker as multiselect in my project. And its working fine.and also I have a on change event to fire url on selecting the selectbox.

I want to know on click or change which item is clicked. (which option of select)

```
$('body').on('change','#mSelect',function(e){
    var val = $(this).val();
})
```

this is giving me the array of all the value which is selected. 
as 
    console.log(val) = ["all","date","blah"]

I want to know which item is clicked which is firing the change event.

please help